# eliminate container div element using only css

Tags: css

I have this structure:

```
<div clas="page_cat_list">
    <div class="page_cat_row">
        <div class="page_cat_item">...</div>
        <div class="page_cat_item">...</div>
        <div class="page_cat_item">...</div>
        <div class="clear_fix"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="page_cat_row">
        <div class="page_cat_item">...</div>
        <div class="page_cat_item">...</div>
        <div class="page_cat_item">...</div>
        <div class="clear_fix"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this displays 3 items in a row, but I need the page_cat_list 100% width, and as many items they fit in the row dinamically.

I used:

```
.clear_fix {
    display: none;
}
```

that`s ok, and

```
.page_cat_row{
    display: inline;
}
```

this way I have as many items as they fit in the row, but they are aligned left, I tried:

```
    .page_cat_row, page_cat_list {
    text-align: center;
}
```

but is not working
the best solution should be to eliminate the .page_cat_row element, from CSS if possibile, because I have no access to html.

---

It is supposed to behave like this:

```
<div clas="page_cat_list">
    <div class="page_cat_item">...</div>
    <div class="page_cat_item">...</div>
    <div class="page_cat_item">...</div>
    <div class="page_cat_item">...</div>
    <div class="page_cat_item">...</div>
    <div class="page_cat_item">...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: How is this ***supposed*** to look?

Comment: Please don't add code in comments. An image is what is required here. It's unclear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

`.page_cat_item` is a div and by default 100% width so you need to center align content inside this div not the whole this

```
.page_cat_item {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Also the css you were using is having an error

```
.page_cat_row, page_cat_list {
    text-align: center;
}
```

> In your above css you need to define `.` for both classes not just for first

This is correct

```
.page_cat_row, page_cat_list {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: In the page you posted the layout it is just like you asked for in this question as i see.